# iniciante com duvida em código

Tags: javascript, html

ola! 
Comecei a estudar agora logica de programação, e estava fazendo um programa para  calcular o imc, só que por algum motivo quando uso a função parseInt na minha variável de peso e altura ele não faz o calculo certo.
segue o codigo:

```
<meta charset = "utf-8">


<script>


function escrever(txt) {

    document.write( txt + "<br>");
}

alert("calculadora imc");

var nome = prompt("qual seu nome?");
var altura = parseInt(prompt("qual sua altura?"));
var peso = parseInt(prompt("qual o seu peso?"));
var calculaimc = (peso / (altura*altura));

escrever(nome + " o valor do seu imc é de: " + calculaimc);

if(calculaimc <= 18.5){
    escrever("seu imc esta abaixo do recomendado.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 18.6 && calculaimc <= 24.9){
    escrever("seu imc esta normal.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 25 && calculaimc <= 29.9){
    escrever(" seu imc indica sobrepeso.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 30 && calculaimc <= 39.9){
    escrever(" seu imc indica obesidade.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 40){
    escrever( "seu imc esta muito acima do recomendado.");
    alert("procure um medico");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

parsenInt() esta funcionando corretamente. Quando você passa um valor de ponto flutuante ex. "39.9" ou 39.9 ele é convertido para um valor inteiro 39, parseFloat() por sua vez converte para um valor de ponto flutuante ex. "39.9" será convertido para 39.9 ou 39 será convertido para 39.0.
Para corrigir o seu problema basta usar parseFloat() no lugar de parseInt().

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está utilizando a função [`parseInt(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), que analisa um argumento string e retorna um inteiro, para analisar duas entrada que pertencem ao domínio dos números reais.

Se pegar por exemplo os meus dados cujo a `altura == 1.86` e o `peso == 85`, o `imc` calculado com `parseInt(string)` seria `imc == 85`, pois `parseInt(1.86) == 1` e o programa me recomendaria um médico.

Para resolver você deve usar [`parseFloat(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) que analisa um argumento string e retorna um número de ponto flutuante.

Então com os mesmos dados e a função `parseFloat(string)` meu índice de massa corporal é `24.5693143716` pois `parseFloat(1.86) == 1.86`.

```js
function escrever(txt) {

    document.write( txt + "<br>");
}

alert("calculadora imc");

var nome = prompt("qual seu nome?");
var altura = parseFloat(prompt("qual sua altura?"));
var peso = parseFloat(prompt("qual o seu peso?"));
console.log("Peso :" + peso);
console.log("Altura :" + altura);
var calculaimc = (peso / (altura*altura));

escrever(nome + " o valor do seu imc é de: " + calculaimc);

if(calculaimc <= 18.5){
    escrever("seu imc esta abaixo do recomendado.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 18.6 && calculaimc <= 24.9){
    escrever("seu imc esta normal.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 25 && calculaimc <= 29.9){
    escrever(" seu imc indica sobrepeso.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 30 && calculaimc <= 39.9){
    escrever(" seu imc indica obesidade.");
}

if(calculaimc >= 40){
    escrever( "seu imc esta muito acima do recomendado.");
    alert("procure um medico");
}
```